# Regexp matching spaces in words

Tags: php, regex

I am looking for a regular expression for replacing words written like "w o r d", 
"o v e r f low" to "word" and "overflow", respectively, all over the input string (including at the beginning and the end).

I'm using PHP & preg_replace. And need to detect those words before splitting string by space and further filtering. Any combinations for the time gives no due result.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i guess it has to ignore the spaces between words? tricky

Comment: how do you handle this for example : `it is a code` ==> `it isacode`, or u are dealing only words, no sentense

Comment: You need a dictionary of valid words and a language more powerful than regex. There will also be some ambiguous cases. Should `a b r o a d` become `abroad` or `a broad`?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing

Answer (score 0):

this one is hard because: what is a word? what is a part of a word?

What is different between `in cr e di ble` and `it is a dog` ?

For that to work with regex you need to set rules, for example:

- How many whitespaces can be between words, and between word parts?
- How long are the parts a word can be divided in?
- Are ALL the words in the string divided in parts?

If you can't be sure of any of those rules then you can't write a regex that will solve the problem. Comparing the words to a dictionary to know if they are valid or not should prove more useful.

Comment: Yes, "in cr e di ble" and "it is a dog" is different. I'm checking, if a symbol(limited by spaces) not a "a|&" and there are more than one symbol previously, and there are more than 1 symbol nextly. And then remove spaces around it or something else...

Answer (score 0):

```
$ string = "w o r d", "o v e r f low"
$ echo 'word w o r d' | sed '/\([^ ][^ ]\)[ ]/s::\1\n:g ' | sed '/[ ]\([^ ][^ ]\)/s::\n\1:g' | sed ':r /\([^ ]\)[ ]/s::\1: ; tr' | sed 'H; ${x;/\n/s:: :g;sc[ ]cc;p};d'
```

Comment: Ok, but what if: 
echo "trololo w o r d lolo", "trolo o v e r f low lololo" | sed ':r /\([^ ]\) \([^ ]\)/s::\1\2: ; tr'
?

Comment: You forgot to insert the backslash before the parenthesis.

Comment: I wrote `\([^ ]\)` , not `/([^ ])`

Comment: Still the same. If string will contain a few words it will merge them all:

# echo 'word w o r d' | sed ':r /\([^ ]\) \([^ ]\)/s::\1\2: ; tr'
wordword

Comment: try it now. Probably this variant is what you need.

Comment: Thanks! This is very closely what I need. Currently I can't get proper result when running that command via php's exec with cyrylic symbols. It just returns the same string. But when I simply coping and pasting the whole command from the debuger into my CLI, it works! I've checked encoding and within latin symbols - everything processed correctly. Any guesses?